# Issue with dynamically adding Option tag to Select tag in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have my [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/expensetracker-wrgfb) which is almost complete. But the problem is a small bug in my drop down box with is dynamic, which means whenever a new expense is added to the list, the corresponding year gets added to the `options tag` within `select tag` in `FilterExpense.jsx` file. The issue goes like even if a particular year is present in the drop down list, the same year gets added again and again all the time when an expense of the same year is added to the list.

Here is the picture showing two `2021` while the program is expected to show it only once.  How to fix this bug?

[image]

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: You've not included the relevant code in your question, and the link to project is now broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eliminate duplicates inside your `addYear` function by using a `Set`. The following example will gather all of the four-digit years, use a `Set` to eliminate duplicates, and then spread that set into an array and create options.

```js
function addYear() {
  const items = sendYear.map((preValue) =>
    new Date(preValue.date).getFullYear()
  );

  return [...new Set(items)].map((year) => {
    return (
      <option key={year} value={year}>
        {year}
      </option>
    );
  });
}
```

I also wanted to note for you that the `.getFullYear()` method might yield unexpected results. For example, `new Date('2021-01-01').getFullYear();` for me (in Eastern Daylight Time) actually returns `2020`. Instead, since your date format is consistently YYYY-MM-DD, you could consider getting the year by doing `preValue.date.split('-')[0]`.